# merging subdirectories with the same name

Tags: linux, merge, directory

Perhaps I am mistaken, but I did not see a satisfactory answer for this question yet.

I have two directories which contain ~100 subdirectories. Within the directories, each subdirectory has the same name(s).

For example the first directory will have subdir1, subdir2, subdir3 and the second directory will have subdir1 subdir2, subdir3.

Within each subdirectory are files that need to all end up in one of the two subdirectories.

So basically I need a way of matching the identical subdirectory names and adding the files from one into the other. So that all the files from directory1/subdir1 and directory2/subdir1 end up in the same place.

There are too many files to make doing this manually very practical.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you initially have space for two full copies.  If so, you can just sync / copy both ways and then delete one of the lots.

Comment: Soo maybe I didn't understand the question right but why not something like `cp -R a/* b` (assuming base directories are named a and b)

Comment: use rsync command:
[enter link description here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149965/how-to-copy-merge-two-directories)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just

```
cp -r source/ target/
```

Or, maybe

```
for name in subdir1 subdir2 subdir3; do cp -r */"$name"/; done
```

Add `-v` to see what gets copied. `-u` for "updates only"

Comment: I suppose I was hoping for something high throughput, such that it would work iteratively through the directories without my having to type in the commands for each directory 100 times.

Comment: Erm, the first command is already it. Nothing else. The second command is in case you need to be selective. But it's a single command. It doesn't really get much higher throughput.

Answer (score 0):

Use commands like these

```
>mkdir your_new_dir
>do for j in 1 100; do mkdir your_new_dir/subdir${j}; done
>for i in 1 2; do for j in `seq 1 100`; do cp directory${i}/subdir{$j}/* your_new_dir/subdir${j}/; done;done
```

Note that your files will be overwritten if they have the same name.